# Where to find remembered luks password for USB drive

Tags: luks

I have an external USB drive that is encrypted with LUKS. I have always let Ubuntu remember the password for me and now I have forgotten the password. The drive is automatically unlocked when I plug it in to my machine, so Ubuntu has the key/password stored somewhere. How can I find the password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This brings up a dialog to let you view/copy the safely stored password:

1. open the Gnome "Passwords and Keys" application (a.k.a. "Seahorse")
2. in the sidebar on the left, click on "Login" (you may have to provide your login password to unlock this keyring)
3. in the vertical ellipsis menu (⋮), make sure you're filtering "Show any"
4. your devices will appear; right-click on the device and chose "Properties"

(Just tried this successfully with Gnome 3.38 on Debian/bullseye.)

Comment: Works on Linux Fedora (38), too...